# How to include our header files using angular brackets in C++?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have my header files for ex, header.h and I want to include in a `.cpp` file using <>, it is showing error as "`Can not fin the  file.`".

I know for header files included using <>, the compiler searches them at the specified location, but how to tell the compiler to search the header files at a particular location while compiling the code.

I have tried,

> g++ -I/src/include filename.cpp

but it shows same error as above.

Please suggest me the way to solve this problem.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: You do know that a leading `/` in a path (like in `/src/include`) makes the path *absolute*? Perhaps you should try just `src/include`?

Comment: The quotation `#include "filename"` is used for the headers you define. Also it falls back to angular brackets if doesn't find anything.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. Question is about angled brackets. Duplicate answer only mentions -I, which won't work for code with angled brackets.